# How can I do this using DevExpress XtraReports

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I have a report with the following set up, the issue is that i need to grab the OrderDate into my link, but when I use HtmlItemCreated , the OrderDate is created after the CreditCard label so I cant ever grab the text of the OrderDate label. Or how can I do this?, I know I can grab the e.Brick.Text when I am in the HtmlItemCreated but, I cant do it there because its being created first then the other one that has the value. This is being created first

```
private void xrLabel200_HtmlItemCreated(object sender, HtmlEventArgs e)
```

and then this

```
 private void OrderDate_HtmlItemCreated(object sender, HtmlEventArgs e)
```

My Issue again is that I need the OrderDate created in the OrderDate_HtmlItemCreated but , its being generated after it has gone through xrlabel200's evernt handler.

I dont know what to do I have tried changing the positions of the handlers etc.. and nothing.. here is a snapshot of the report if anyone can help me out

The OrderDate is at the header, the CardType is a link and thats where I am trying to append the date.. as follows

under

```
 private void xrLabel200_HtmlItemCreated(object sender, HtmlEventArgs e)
{
 string cardTypeName = e.Brick.Text;

        switch (cardTypeName)
        {
            case "N/A":
                CardTypeID = 0;
                break;
            case "MASTER CARD":
                CardTypeID = 1;
                break;
        }
//OrderDate.Text is always returning XRLabel3 (which is the name) because it has not been populated
link.HRef = string.Format("mywebsite.aspx?sDate={0}&ctId={2}", OrderDate.Text, CardTypeID);
        link.InnerText = e.Brick.Text;
        link.Target = "blank";
        currentCell.Controls.Clear();
        currentCell.Controls.Add(link);
        currentCell.Attributes.Remove("onmousedown");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant you base your code on the contents of the underlying datasource rather than the displayed report contents?

Doing this would mean you have no requirements to process code in a specific order.

e.g. [GetCurrentColumnValue](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReportBase_GetCurrentColumnValuetopic)